# Understanding the "Reset" button for the "iOS Development" for "Personal Team"

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, ios-provisioning, code-signing-certificate

I added an Apple ID in XCode's Account. 
Note at this point there are no certificates or provisioning profiles in the developer portal.

For the "Personal Team" team, the "iOS Development' signing identity it showed a "Reset" button. 
After I clicked on the Reset button, in Keychain Access it created the keys and certificate.

But in the member center portal no certificates were created.
Shouldn't it had created one?

Next, I went to the "Agent" team, the "iOS Development' signing identity had a "Create" button (not a "Reset" one). 
I clicked on "Create" and it created keys and certificate locally but it also created certificate in the member center portal!

My question is, why clicking on "Reset" for "Personal Team" didn't create certificates in member center?